# Replace Game Piece with an Image

Tags: javascript

I want to make a version of the classic helicopter game, however I want to replace the piece with an image. Annoyingly it's proving to be difficult...

I have tried replacing the game piece with this code

```
function startGame() {
    myGameArea = enter code herenew gamearea();
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "image.png", 10, 75, "image");
    myscore = new component("15px", "Consolas", "black", 220, 25, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

However the image doesn't show.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="myfilter" style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.3; width: 322px; height: 182px; display: block;"></div>
<div id="myrestartbutton" style="position: absolute; padding-top: 75px; padding-left: 120px; display: block;"><button onclick="restartGame()">Restart</button></div>
<div id="canvascontainer"><canvas width="320" height="180"></canvas></div>
<br>
<div style="text-align:center;width:320px;">
  <button ontouchstart="moveup()" onmousedown="moveup()" onmouseup="clearmove()">UP</button><br><br>
  <button ontouchstart="moveleft()" onmousedown="moveleft()" onmouseup="clearmove()">LEFT</button>
  <button ontouchstart="moveright()" onmousedown="moveright()" onmouseup="clearmove()">RIGHT</button><br><br>
  <button ontouchstart="movedown()" onmousedown="movedown()" onmouseup="clearmove()">DOWN</button>
</div>
<br>

<script>

var myGameArea;
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myscore;

function restartGame() {
document.getElementById("myfilter").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("myrestartbutton").style.display = "none";
myGameArea.stop();
myGameArea.clear();
myGameArea = {};
myGamePiece = {};
myObstacles = [];
myscore = {};
document.getElementById("canvascontainer").innerHTML = "";
startGame()
}

function startGame() {
    myGameArea = new gamearea();
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "image.png", 10, 75, "image");
    myscore = new component("15px", "Consolas", "black", 220, 25, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

function gamearea() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.canvas.width = 320;
    this.canvas.height = 180;    
    document.getElementById("canvascontainer").appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.pause = false;
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.start = function() {
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    }
    this.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.pause = true;
    }
    this.clear = function(){
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

    this.type = type;
    if (type == "text") {
        this.text = color;
    }
    this.score = 0;    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, y, min, max, height, gap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            myGameArea.stop();
            document.getElementById("myfilter").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("myrestartbutton").style.display = "block";
            return;
        } 
    }
    if (myGameArea.pause == false) {
        myGameArea.clear();
        myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
        myscore.score +=1;        
        if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
            x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
            y = myGameArea.canvas.height - 100;
            min = 20;
            max = 100;
            height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
            min = 50;
            max = 100;
            gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            myObstacles[i].x += -1;
            myObstacles[i].update();
        }
        myscore.text="SCORE: " + myscore.score;        
        myscore.update();
        myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
        myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;    
        myGamePiece.update();
    }
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function moveup(e) {
    myGamePiece.speedY = -1; 
}

function movedown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 1; 
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -1; 
}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 1; 
}

function clearmove(e) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0; 
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0; 
}
startGame();

</script>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<h1>Desi-copter</h1>
<p>Push the buttons to move Nice Guy Des</p>
<div id="myfilter" style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.3; width: 322px; height: 182px; display: block;"></div>
<div id="myrestartbutton" style="position: absolute; padding-top: 75px; padding-left: 120px; display: block;"><button onclick="restartGame()">Restart</button></div>
<div id="canvascontainer"><canvas width="320" height="180"></canvas></div>
<br>
<div style="text-align:center;width:320px;">
  <button ontouchstart="moveup()" onmousedown="moveup()" onmouseup="clearmove()">UP</button><br><br>
  <button ontouchstart="moveleft()" onmousedown="moveleft()" onmouseup="clearmove()">LEFT</button>
  <button ontouchstart="moveright()" onmousedown="moveright()" onmouseup="clearmove()">RIGHT</button><br><br>
  <button ontouchstart="movedown()" onmousedown="movedown()" onmouseup="clearmove()">DOWN</button>
</div>
<br>

<script>

var myGameArea;
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myscore;

function restartGame() {
document.getElementById("myfilter").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("myrestartbutton").style.display = "none";
myGameArea.stop();
myGameArea.clear();
myGameArea = {};
myGamePiece = {};
myObstacles = [];
myscore = {};
document.getElementById("canvascontainer").innerHTML = "";
startGame()
}

function startGame() {
    myGameArea = new gamearea();
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "image.png", 10, 75, "image");
    myscore = new component("15px", "Consolas", "black", 220, 25, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

function gamearea() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.canvas.width = 320;
    this.canvas.height = 180;    
    document.getElementById("canvascontainer").appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.pause = false;
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.start = function() {
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    }
    this.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.pause = true;
    }
    this.clear = function(){
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

    this.type = type;
    if (type == "text") {
        this.text = color;
    }
    this.score = 0;    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, y, min, max, height, gap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            myGameArea.stop();
            document.getElementById("myfilter").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("myrestartbutton").style.display = "block";
            return;
        } 
    }
    if (myGameArea.pause == false) {
        myGameArea.clear();
        myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
        myscore.score +=1;        
        if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
            x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
            y = myGameArea.canvas.height - 100;
            min = 20;
            max = 100;
            height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
            min = 50;
            max = 100;
            gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            myObstacles[i].x += -1;
            myObstacles[i].update();
        }
        myscore.text="SCORE: " + myscore.score;        
        myscore.update();
        myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
        myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;    
        myGamePiece.update();
    }
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function moveup(e) {
    myGamePiece.speedY = -1; 
}

function movedown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 1; 
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -1; 
}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 1; 
}

function clearmove(e) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0; 
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0; 
}
startGame();

</script>
</html>
```

"This is a version of the helicopter game. What I am trying to achieve is to replace the square with image.png. The above is all of the code that I have used to date. I have tried replacing the game piece section of the code with an image, however the image doesn't take priority for some reason and isn't been shown. Please can somebody point out where I am going wrong with this?"

Comment: That is a lot of code - it might be easier for you to get help if you could reduce this down to the only parts required.

Comment: I know it's a lot of code, the problem is I don't know what part is stopping the image from being seen so I had to post it all sadly.